# issues with "crop on the fly" in cropper.js

Tags: image, crop

hello a have some issues with "crop on the fly" in cropper.js plugin

```
function cropPreview(img) {
            var $toCrop = $(img);
            $toCrop.cropper({
                autoCropArea: 0.1,
                viewMode: 3,
                strict: true,
                guides: false,
                zoomable: false,
                dragMode: 'none',
                highlight: false,
                cropBoxResizable: false,
                minCropBoxWidth: 204,
                minCropBoxHeight: 140,
                minCanvasHeight: 140,
                minCanvasWidth: 204,
                ready: function () {
                        var canvas = $toCrop.cropper('getCroppedCanvas');
                        img.src    = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                        img.setAttribute('data-cropped', true);
                        $toCrop.cropper('destroy');
                }
            });
        }
```

in chrome browser 90 percent of images looks after crop like black square.
this method called in ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/create-adv/save-tmp-image',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                var $obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                cropPreview(addUplImgToList($obj.image_data));
            },
        });
function addUplImgToList(img_src) {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = img_src;
        img.setAttribute('data-src', img_src);
        img.setAttribute('data-main', img_src);
        img.onload = function (e) {
            $('.img-loader-input').remove();
        }
        return img;
    }
```

for desktop i have fixed this issue via timeout
but for mobile it's still exists.

P.S. Sorry for my terrible english)